# Referenced text from other sheet not displayed as result

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I previously had this working in my Google Sheet, but for some reason it no longer is.

I want to reference a cell from another sheet, for example, from the sheet titled 'Overall'

I type `=Overall!N10` into the cell

I can see that it is the right formula because when I double click on the cell (to show the formula preview) it shows me the text in the box 'Difficult conversations'. However when click off that, it just show some other text "Palliative care".

I don't know why it's not displaying the formula preview in the cell:

[image]

Comment: Not sure. It worked for me when I typed in a different sheet and cell (though it did take a second to register). Is `Palliative care` somewhere else in the workbook?

Comment: I can delete palliative care.

Comment: If I put the formula into another cell, the cell looks blank. Except when I click to show the formula preview I can that it's right (as per the screenshot)